# Magento2: Configurable product attribute issue

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, product-attribute

I have created a configurable product using Size attribute(Text swatch type).

When I create a configurable product some size also assigned to the parent configurable product automatically So even I am not using that size in child products, it also showing in filter result of that attribute.

Size attribute also used in layered navigation, so when user filter the products using size, configurable product showing in filter result.

[click here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/26449) for More information